# How to get MAX numeric value from a column with char values in MySql

Tags: mysql, max

I would like to know how can I get the max value only within the numeric values in a column with char values in a MySql database:

Supposing the column is as follows:

```
 col  
---------
ALL      
USD      
USD      
RET      
RET      
ACC      
ACC      
ALL      
ALL      
ERR      
ERR      
PRO      
PRO      
1        
1        
2        
2        
3        
3        
4        
4        
5        
5        
6        
6        
7        
7        
8        
8        
9        
9        
AY       
AY       
C        
C        
CF
```

I should get 9 as a result of my query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the numbers are all Integer, that you want

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(col AS SIGNED)) from nextg WHERE col REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

Like @Akina said in the comments MySQL knows another way

```
SELECT MAX(col + 0) from nextg WHERE col REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=192cb85de1c8ab8ea77b7f8c37bcf3da)

If you have also Decimal Numbers.

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(col AS DECIMAL(8,2))) from nextg WHERE col 
REGEXP '^[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*$'
```

Comment: Should you not cast to number before applying max? Otherwise 9>10

Comment: Oh thx missed it

Comment: `SELECT MAX(col + 0) from nextg;` is enough. Or `SELECT MAX(col + 0) from nextg  WHERE col REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';` if values like `'99ASD'` are present.